# ed - line editor (what does $p do?)

Tags: unix, vim, vi, ed

I am using ed a unix line editor and the book i'm reading says to type 1,$p 
(also works in vim)

after trial and error I figured the first value means the line number but whats the purpose to $p? from what i can tell is the 1 goes to the beginning of the line and $p goes to the EOF and displays to me everything it picked up. is this true or am i way off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1,$` part is a range. The comma separates the beginning and end of the range. In this case, 1 (line 1) is the beginning, and $ (EOF) is the end. The `p` means print, which is the command the range is being given to, and yes.. it displays to you what is in that range.

In vim you can look at `:help :range` and `:help :print` to find out more about how this works. These types of ranges are also used by `sed` and other editors.

They probably used the `1,$` terminology in the tutorial to be explicit, but note that you can also use `%` as its equivalent. Thus, `%p` will also print all the lines in the file.

Comment: thank you for that very clear explanation!, i'm not there yet in the book but what other commands can i put instead of print? And is there a way to clear the output like the terminal command clear?

Comment: @SarmenB. Here's a list of [commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Commands). The ones with `(.,.)` in front of them take a range, but default to using the current line. The ones with `(1,$)` in front of them also take a range, but default to using the entire file.